# Getting a fixed legend colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have three plots with pandas. In one of the plots there does not exist the number "2", so all the colors of the categories are different to those of the two others. Is it possible to have a fixed colormap?

Here are the three plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is how one of the plots is constructed:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

columns = ['Radius', 'FRC', 'Scoring']
df = pd.DataFrame(bestof10, columns=columns)
out = {}
for column in columns:
    out[column] = pd.value_counts(df[column])

uniq_df = pd.DataFrame(out).fillna(0)

test = uniq_df.T.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, ax =ax,rot=0)

#ax.legend(loc='best');
ax.set_ylabel("frequency")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1), loc='upper right', ncol=1)
plt.savefig("WithoutInfluenceOfParameterBestOf10.png",bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be fill in all the non-existing values in your data frame (I had problems positioning the legend the way you do, that's why I used GridSpec):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols = 5, nrows = 12)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,8))
axes = [
    fig.add_subplot(gs[4*i:4*(i+1),:-1]) for i in range(3)
]

columns = ['Radius', 'FRC', 'Scoring']
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame({
        'FRC' :     sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([0,0,3,7,0,0,0,])],[]),
        'Radius' :  sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([0,0,1,9,0,0,0,])],[]),
        'Scoring' : sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([1,0,1,2,1,2,3,])],[]),
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'FRC' :     sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([0,1,8,11,0,0,0,])],[]),
        'Radius' :  sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([0,0,5,15,0,0,0,])],[]),
        'Scoring' : sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([3,2,3,3, 2,3,4,])],[]),
    }),
    pd.DataFrame({
        'FRC' :     sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([0,1,8,11,0,0,0,])],[]),
        'Radius' :  sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([0,0,5,15,0,0,0,])],[]),
        'Scoring' : sum([[i+1]*n for i,n in enumerate([3,2,3,3, 2,3,4,])],[]),
    }),
]
#collect all possible values in a set() by looping through all 
#dataframes
all_vals=set()    
for df in dfs:
    for column in columns:
        all_vals.update(df[column])

#looping through the data frames again to produce the plots           
for bestof,ax in zip(dfs, axes):    
    df = pd.DataFrame(bestof, columns=columns)
    out = {}
    for column in columns:
        out[column] = pd.value_counts(df[column])

        for val in all_vals:
            if val not in out[column]:
                out[column][val] = 0

    uniq_df = pd.DataFrame(out).fillna(0)

    test = uniq_df.T.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, ax=ax, rot=0)

    ax.legend(loc='best');
    ax.set_ylabel("frequency")
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1), loc='upper right', ncol=1)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This code produces the following figure:
[image: bar plots with correct legends]

Hope this helps.